# What is exactly the importLoaders option of css-loader in Webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I've started learning Webpack 4 since a month. Most things I wanted to do is working great but this `importLoaders` option of `css-loader` is still a mystery for me. Its official [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#importloaders) is poor and I haven't found any well explained writing about it.

My use case is very close to the one presented in the documentation:

```
{
  test: /\.s?css$/,
  use: [
    ExtractCssChunks.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 2, // 0 => no loaders (default); 1 => postcss-loader; 2 => postcss-loader, sass-loader
        import: true, // is true by default, but should I use instead false here???
        url: false // let postcss do it
      }
    },
    'postcss-loader',
    'sass-loader'
  ]
}
```

And my vendors.scss for example with different kind of imports:

```
@charset 'UTF-8';

// Google fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|Dosis:200,400,500,600');

//FontAwesome (from node_modules)
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles";

// Site theme
@import "theme/index";
```

Basically I want `sass-loader` to do its usual job and `postcss` to do some manipulation with image files.

**So when and why should I use 0/1/2/n for `importLoaders` option?**
How is it affected to my `@imports` above?

Could someone explain it to me more detailed like in the docs?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After more searching it turned out that I'm not the only one confused about how to use this option correctly. Issues from the GitHub repo of `css-loader`:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/765

Also see @guidobouman excellent explanation here:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/228#issuecomment-312885975

So this answers my question (quoted literally):

> `importLoaders` only has effect on unresolved `@import`s. So when using
>   postCSS with nextCSS (no `@import` resolver) you'll want to set
>   `importLoaders`. This way nextCSS will also be applied to imported `.css`
>   files. But when using sass, it already handles the `@import` statements,
>   so no `importLoaders` is required.
>
> So, this only happens when `css-loader` finds an unresolved `@import`.
>   When using `sass-loader` for example; All imports are resolved (and
>   concatenated) before `css-loader` even gets the chance to look for an
>   `@import`.